# Is Producer Consumer Problem without locks and atomics possible?

Tags: synchronization, mutex, semaphore, producer-consumer

I have come up with a code that seems to work for the single producer - single consumer problem. I am not using any locks or atomics. Is there anything I am missing?

```
const int LEN = 10;
int q[LEN];

volatile int loc1 = 0;
volatile int loc2 = 0;


void* consumer(void* arg) {

    while(1) {
        while(loc1 == loc2);
        int val = q[loc1];
        loc1 = (loc1 + 1) % LEN;
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* producer(void* arg) {

    while(1) {
        while((loc2 + 1) % LEN == loc1);
        q[loc2] = getItem();
        loc2 = (loc2 + 1) % LEN;
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I ran some stress tests but this didn't fail.

The while loop in producer waits until the queue has less than LEN - 1 elements before producing a new element. I basically prevent the queue from completely filling up.

Comment: The compiler is free to not re-check the value of loc2 in the consumer and the value of loc1 in producer. As those values are not being changed in the loop, the compiler may generate code that loads the value once and then sticks with it (that would break your code). This is more likely if you enable optimizations in the compiler. It may be mitigated somewhat by marking those variables as volatile (which disables most optimizations for them).

Comment: How do you know it works so well. The consumer does nothing with the value it reads. What would the program results look like if it did not work properly?

Comment: In the stress test, I produced integers starting from 0 and incrementing by one. Then I asserted that values come in the same order. I ran this for a few minutes and this didn't fail.
Other incorrect approaches like maintaining a common count variable (to check if queue is full or empty), failed in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an article about a formal proof of a single-producer single-consumer implementation without locks, but using atomics:
https://blog.adacore.com/from-rust-to-spark-formally-proven-bip-buffers

Comment: Yes it is easy to do that using atomics. In the code above, I do not use any atomics.

Comment: Your code implements a form of a spin lock. It is not lock-free code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock#:~:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20a%20spinlock,a%20kind%20of%20busy%20waiting.